# PL/SQL: Join between two tables error

Tags: sql, join, plsql

I have got a task in which I have to display information from two different tables using a cursor. I tried doing it with an example we did before, but it doesn't seem to work! Below mentioned are the two tables that I have to take records from and display them.

**'Emp' Table**

[image: 'Emp' Table]

**'Dept' Table**

[image: 'Dept' Table]

I want to display all the employee number, names, salary, department name and department location they working in.

Below is what I did:

```
 set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  CURSOR staff_cursor IS
  SELECT e.empno,e.ename,e.sal, d.dname, d.dloc FROM emp e, dept d
  WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno;
  v_eno emp.empno%type;
  v_lname emp.ename%type;
  v_esal emp.sal%type;
  v_ddname dept.dname%type;
  v_dloc dept.dloc%type;

BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('******************');
  OPEN staff_cursor;
  FETCH staff_cursor into v_eno, v_lname, v_esal, v_ddname, v_dloc;
  WHILE staff_cursor%found LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_eno);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_lname);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_esal);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('******************');
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_ddname);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_dloc);

     FETCH staff_cursor into v_eno, v_lname, v_esal, v_ddname, v_dloc;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE staff_cursor;
END;
```

It gives me error something about D.DLOC invalid identifier. I don't understand what is the problem, I’m hoping someone could help me in it.

Comment: Please stop using the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) in preference for explicitly listing joins (`FROM emp e JOIN dept d ON e.deptno = d.deptno`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cursor does select `d.dloc`of the table `dept d`, but it is named `loc` in your screenshot.

```
CURSOR staff_cursor IS
  SELECT e.empno, e.ename, e.sal, d.dname, d.loc
  -- ...
```